# Security Threat - composer/installed.json

Tags: php, security, composer-php, owasp

I recently ran a vulnerability scan on one of my applications, and it stated that my 'composer/installed.json' file was accessible and may expose sensitive information. This was regarded by the scanner as a 'high' vulnerability.

Suffice to say, I've not found any decent information to resolve this issue.

Firstly, is it safe to delete this file? or is it a key requirement in addition to composer.json and composer.lock?

If not, should I be doing something with my Apache virtual host, or a '.htaccess' file within this folder to prevent access to this file?

The threat details specifically highlighted this portion as well, so I'm not entirely sure if it is relating more to doctrine, which is a dependency of something.

```
"suggest": {
      "doctrine/cache": "**Adds support for caching of credentials and responses**",
      "ext-apc": "Allows service description opcode caching, request and response caching, and credentials caching",
      "ext-openssl": "Allows working with CloudFront private distributions and verifying received SNS messages",
      "monolog/monolog": "Adds support for logging HTTP requests and responses",
      "symfony/yaml": "Eases the ability to write manifests for creating jobs in AWS Import/Export"
    },
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Thanks

James

Comment: it's recommended to put composer.json and all of its associated packages to the parent directory of your website root which contains the index.php file, this way you're safe.

Answer (score 4):

If your `./vendor` directory, (that file is `vendor/composer/installed.json`) is accessible from a browser, then you have a bigger issue than a JSON file.

The only directory that should be available to download is your `./public` (or maybe `./web`) directory with an index.php file (the 'front controller') and the css, javascript, images, and other files that make up your website and would need to be downloaded in a browser.

That file is a note from Composer as to what other packages make up the rest of the vendor directory - and is assembled from the `composer.json` files in the other packages, in a similar way as the `composer.lock` file.